# Concatenate two object columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to conceatenate three columns of datatype object. I am reading a XLSM file:

```
for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".XLSM"): 
        file_dir = os.path.join(input_dir, filename)
        df = pd.read_excel(file_dir, sheet_name=0)

        B = df["- "]  
        F = df["Merk "]
        G =  df["Farbe "]
```

the table has following content:

```
ID   -                          Merk       Farbe

1   Fencheltee lang Metall-     -        schwarz
2   Hose BR Damen1/4 Silikon    48       weiß
3   Sonnecream AR 200Ml. SAL30  34       Snow white
.
.
```

I am trying to write a new csv file that should look like this:

```
ACTIVE,NAME 
A,Fencheltee lang Metall- - schwarz
A,Hose BR Damen1/4 Silikon 48 weiß
A,Cream AR 200Ml. SAL30 34 Snow white
```

How can I join cloumn B, F and G of dataType object to coulmn NAME in my output csv file?
I have tried following, but I am getting a csv file with empty NAME values.

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ACTIVE", "NAME"], index = ID)
df_["ACTIVE"] = 1
df_["NAME"] = B + " " + F + " " + G

        
df_.to_csv('output/pfiff.csv', encoding = 'utf-8', index=False)
```

And this is the wrong output:

```
ACTIVE,NAME
1,
1,
1,
1,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the columns of df you want to have into the new DataFrame like this:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "NAME"])
df_["NAME"] = df["- "] + " " + df["Merk"].astype(str) + " " + df["Farbe "]
df_["A"] = "A"
```

Comment: no this is wrong, the variable B is already `df["- "] `, and `F = df["Merk "] `, `G =  df["Farbe "] `, please read my question properly

Comment: You can tread the 'B's and 'F's as placeholders and just replace them with the column name you would like to have, so for example df_["NAME"] = df["- "] + " " + df["Merk "] + " " + df["Farbe "]

Comment: that doesn't work either, I suppose it has something to do with the dataType .... the columns are dataType object and not string

Comment: Why are you storing the columns of df in variables (like B,F,G)? You can just keep it as a whole dataframe and then work with df["- "], df["Merk "] and so on

Comment: as I have said, keeping it as a whole dataframe doesn't work either. I think this isn't the cause of the problem

Comment: Hm.. okay, well last thing I could try is to look at the .XLSM (or a part of it) if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216732/discussion-between-jonas-and-lazzat).

Answer (score 0):

removing `index = ID` solved my problem!

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ACTIVE", "NAME"])
```